# SQL setting a transaction ID to records where grouped by less then 1 second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query that returns a userID and a timestamp. I need to add a column to the query that assigns a transactionID. If a userID has a multiple timestamps that are less than 1 second apart from each other. I need them all to have the same ID.

```
UserID     timestamp                [new column]
1          2016-07-17 18:20:17.373  1
1          2016-07-17 18:21:04.780  2
1          2016-07-19 09:52:36.443  3
1          2016-07-19 09:52:36.460  3
1          2016-07-19 09:53:22.473  4
2          2016-07-19 09:52:36.490  5
2          2016-07-19 09:52:36.553  5
2          2016-07-19 09:53:11.290  6
2          2016-07-19 09:53:11.323  6
2          2016-07-19 09:54:11.211  6
2          2016-07-19 09:55:11.123  6
3          2015-05-12 09:45:56.990  7
3          2015-05-12 09:45:57.007  7
3          2015-05-12 09:45:59.699  8
3          2015-05-12 09:45:60.202  8
```

Note that some users have timestamps that overlap other. Using SQL Server 2008

Any help on accomplishing this would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should avoid using timestamp as a column name. It is also a datatype in sql server that has nothing to do with datetime information. It is also totally ambiguous which you should always avoid in column names. Something like DateInserted would be MUCH clearer.

Comment: I added a new example (userid 3) to the mix

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY userid,SUBSTR(timestamp,1,19) AS newtimestamp ) AS new_column
  FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by datepart(HOUR,[timestamp]), datepart(MI,[timestamp]), datepart(s,[timestamp]) ) AS [New column] 
    FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: This almost worked.. it doesn't work when there are two timestamps like this. 2015-05-12 09:45:56.990 2015-05-12 09:45:57.007

Comment: ms 990 and 007 are only 17 ms away but in different minutes. because of that the DENSE_RANK increments when I don't want it to.  

I've updated the example above and added user 3 to show this logic will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm transaction id for last two rows. It should be 7 and 8.

```
    create table #test(UserID int, [timestamp] datetime)

    insert into #test values
    (1,'2016-07-17 18:20:17.373'),
    (1,'2016-07-17 18:21:04.780'),  
    (1,'2016-07-19 09:52:36.443'),  
    (1,'2016-07-19 09:52:36.460'),  
    (1,'2016-07-19 09:53:22.473'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:52:36.490'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:52:36.553'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:53:11.290'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:53:11.323'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:54:11.211'),  
    (2,'2016-07-19 09:55:11.123')  


    select *, dense_rank()  over( order by UserID, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, [timestamp]), [timestamp])) as [new column]
    from #test
output:
    UserID  timestamp   new column
    1   2016-07-17 18:20:17.373 1
    1   2016-07-17 18:21:04.780 2
    1   2016-07-19 09:52:36.443 3
    1   2016-07-19 09:52:36.460 3
    1   2016-07-19 09:53:22.473 4
    2   2016-07-19 09:52:36.490 5
    2   2016-07-19 09:52:36.553 5
    2   2016-07-19 09:53:11.290 6
    2   2016-07-19 09:53:11.323 6
    2   2016-07-19 09:54:11.210 7
    2   2016-07-19 09:55:11.123 8
```

Comment: This almost worked.. it doesn't work when there are two timestamps like this. 2015-05-12 09:45:56.990 2015-05-12 09:45:57.007